# How can I write a code to obtain the lowest values of each list within a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help writing a code that will help me obtain the lowest number of the each list within a list in python. And then out of the lowest values obtained I must somehow find the highest number of the lowest numbers. I am not allowed to call the built-in functions `min` or `max`, or use any other functions from pre-written modules. How can I go about doing this? I have already tried using the following code:

```
for list in ells:
    sort.list(ells)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not allowed to use built-in functions, you can instead use a variable to keep track of the lowest number you find so far while you iterate through the sublists, and another to keep track of the highest of the lowest numbers you find so far you iterate through the list of lists:

```
l = [
    [2, 5, 7],
    [1, 3, 8],
    [4, 6, 9]
]
highest_of_lowest = None
for sublist in l:
    lowest = None
    for item in sublist:
        if lowest is None or lowest > item:
            lowest = item
    if highest_of_lowest is None or highest_of_lowest < lowest:
        highest_of_lowest = lowest
print(highest_of_lowest)
```

This outputs: `4`

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[6,4,5] 
b=[8,3,9] 
listab=[a,b] 
sorted([sorted(x)[0] for x in listab])[-1]
```

> Output > 4

You can do this for an arbitrary number of lists. This also avoids having  to write your own min and max functions.

Comment: Sorting requires an average time complexity of O(n log n), while finding minimum or maximum should require only O(n).

Comment: True, and by that token @Heagon's first line should do it. However the problem states that the built in min and max should not be used.

Comment: Yes, so you should implement finding minimum and maximum through loops instead of using `min` and `max`.

Comment: Well, IMHO, since the problem makes no comment about efficiency, I would shoot for fewer lines of code.  I'll let the asker pick their route! But thank you for your input, I'm not the most resource economical programmer around!

Comment: Fair enough then.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through your lists and compare to a variable, here using `lo`, if the item is less than the current amount then assign that as the new `lo`. After repeat the process but with `hi` and opposite logic.

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6,], [7, 8, 9]]

lows = []
for i in lst:
    lo = None
    for j in i:
        if lo == None: # to get initial lo
            lo = j
        elif j < lo:
            lo = j
    lows.append(lo)

hi = 0
for i in lows:
    if i > hi:
        hi = i

print(hi)
```

Comment: There's no maximum limit to Python's integers, so picking an arbitrary number assuming the numbers in the given lists will all be lower is not a safe assumption.

Comment: @blhsing I know I was shortcutting, I knew it too when I posted will fix this sorry

Comment: @blhsing welp now my answer looks alot like yours not sure if its even needed :/

Comment: @blhsing appreciate it, ty for the lookout

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the cleanest solution would be to write:

```
max([min(inner_list) for inner_list in list_of_lists])
```

But you said that you were not allowed to use built-in max and min. Well... Why don't we just implement them ourselfs? Here you go:

```
def min(iterable):
    result = iterable[0]
    for element in iterable:
        if element < result:
            result = element 
    return result

def max(iterable):
    result = iterable[0]
    for element in iterable:
        if element > result:
            result = element
    return result
```

Now, that might not be the most robust min and max in the world (and they could sure use more code reuse), but they are short, clear, and will do just fine. Also this would keep the main line of code clear of loops, which make it more difficult to read your code.

And, as an added bonus (which you probably won't need here, but it is a good practice in software design)---your code would have some semblance of SRP, requiring you to only replace the max and min without ever touching the actual logic of your program.

[Here](http://tpcg.io/Tg4u2I) is the full snippet.

Comment: The OP specifically says not to use the `min` or `max` functions.

Comment: @blhsing "I am not allowed to call the **built-in** functions min or max". Which is why I implement them myself.

Comment: @blhsing No problem :D

Comment: Using list comprehension would require materializing the items in the inner list before `max` can start processing them. The cleanest solution would be to use a generator expression instead: `max(min(inner_list) for inner_list in list_of_lists)`.

Comment: Your implementations of `min` and `max` are picking the first item from a given iterable, while iterating through it from the first item again, which is redundant (because it will always be equal to itself). Picking the first item using an index also means it will fail with an iterable that does not implement the `__getitem__` method, such as a set or a generator. You should instead unpack the given iterable: `result, *rest = iterable` and then `for element in rest:`, etc.

Comment: @blhsing I don't think I should use extended unpacking here. For once it is pretty complex stuff. Much more so (in my opinion) than list comprehension. More importantly, it would break compatibility with python 2.

Comment: Unpacking is not complex at all. It makes the code cleaner, more readable and efficient than using an index. If you want compatibility with Python 2 (despite the OP's Python 3 tag) you can use the `iter` function: `iterable = iter(iterable)` and `result = next(iterable)`.